# Delete Items from local storage using their IDs

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I would like to be able to delete an item on my vehicle listing page. When I click delete vehicle button, seems like the ID is not being passed as nothing gets deleted. Below is my vehicle list and delete logic:

```js
vehicleIdsList.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const selectedId = e.target.textContent;
  const selectedVehicle = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(selectedId));

  // Display the selected vehicle details
  vehicleInfo.innerHTML = `
                <p><strong>ID:</strong> ${selectedVehicle.id}</p>
                <p><strong>Transaction Date:</strong> ${selectedVehicle.transactionDate}</p>
                <p><strong>Brand:</strong> ${selectedVehicle.brand}</p>
                <p><strong>Type:</strong> ${selectedVehicle.type}</p>
                <p><strong>Manufacture Year:</strong> ${selectedVehicle.manufactureYear}</p>
                <p><strong>Engine:</strong> ${selectedVehicle.engine}</p>
                <p><strong>Horse Power:</strong> ${selectedVehicle.horsePower}</p>
                <p><strong>Rating:</strong> ${selectedVehicle.rating}</p>
                <p><strong>Comments:</strong> ${selectedVehicle.comments}</p>
            `;

  // Enable the delete button
  deleteButton.disabled = false;
});

// Add click event listener to delete button
deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const selectedId = vehicleInfo.querySelector('p strong:first-child').textContent;

  // Confirm deletion
  const confirmDelete = confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete vehicle with ID: ${selectedId}?`);

  if (confirmDelete) {
    // Delete the vehicle from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem(selectedId);

    // Clear vehicle details
    vehicleInfo.innerHTML = '';

    // Disable the delete button
    deleteButton.disabled = true;

    // Show confirmation message
    alert(`Vehicle with ID: ${selectedId} deleted.`);
  }
});
```

I use the code below to populate the list from local storage. So basically I want to be able to delete an item from the list using their IDs

```js
for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  const id = localStorage.key(i);
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = id;
  vehicleIdsList.appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: The vehicle ID is not in a child of `p strong`. It's in the text node *after* `<strong>ID:</strongz>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `p strong:first-child` is not a selector for the vehicle ID element. That text is *after* `p strong`, not a child of it.

Put that in a span so you can identify it properly. I've used `<span class="vehicle_id">` below.

```js
vehicleIdsList.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const selectedId = e.target.textContent;
  const selectedVehicle = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(selectedId));

  // Display the selected vehicle details
  vehicleInfo.innerHTML = `
                <p><strong>ID:</strong> <span class="vehicle_id">${selectedVehicle.id}</span></p>
                <p><strong>Transaction Date:</strong> ${selectedVehicle.transactionDate}</p>
                <p><strong>Brand:</strong> ${selectedVehicle.brand}</p>
                <p><strong>Type:</strong> ${selectedVehicle.type}</p>
                <p><strong>Manufacture Year:</strong> ${selectedVehicle.manufactureYear}</p>
                <p><strong>Engine:</strong> ${selectedVehicle.engine}</p>
                <p><strong>Horse Power:</strong> ${selectedVehicle.horsePower}</p>
                <p><strong>Rating:</strong> ${selectedVehicle.rating}</p>
                <p><strong>Comments:</strong> ${selectedVehicle.comments}</p>
            `;

  // Enable the delete button
  deleteButton.disabled = false;
});

// Add click event listener to delete button
deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const selectedId = vehicleInfo.querySelector('.vehicle_id').textContent;

  // Confirm deletion
  const confirmDelete = confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete vehicle with ID: ${selectedId}?`);

  if (confirmDelete) {
    // Delete the vehicle from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem(selectedId);

    // Clear vehicle details
    vehicleInfo.innerHTML = '';

    // Disable the delete button
    deleteButton.disabled = true;

    // Show confirmation message
    alert(`Vehicle with ID: ${selectedId} deleted.`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Snippets don't run with localStorage. Either use a plain code block or include a fake storage shim (like my own https://heretic-monkey.link/FauxStorage.js :))

Comment: This isn't intended to run, since it's also missing the HTML. I just didn't bother removing the snippet tags -- it makes editing easier.